# Django How to add user info to Sentry's report when an error happened?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, sentry

I use the django-restful framework and I want to add user info to Sentry's report when an error happened in the ModelViewSet.

I find this doc of Sentry:
https://docs.sentry.io/enriching-error-data/context/?_ga=1.219964441.1220115692.1472094716%3F_ga&platform=python#capturing-the-user

It gives some code as follows:

```py
from sentry_sdk import configure_scope

with configure_scope() as scope:
    scope.user = {"email": "john.doe@example.com"}
```

But I can not figure out how to properly use it. I think there exists a better way than the following:

```py
@list_route()
def fun_xxx(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
  user = request.user
  with configure_scope() as scope:
     scope.user = {"id": user.id,......}

  ...some code may cause an error...

  return Response({...})
```

Can anyone give me some suggestions? :)

Comment: If you're using the Sentry [Django client](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/python/django/), this data is included automatically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the [Django](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/python/django/) integration will attach this particular data automatically.

As for the question on how to generally add data in a Django app, you are basically looking for something to run before each view. A Django middleware suits this:

```
def sentry_middleware(get_response):

    def middleware(request):
        with configure_scope() as scope:
            ...

        response = get_response(request)
        return response

    return middleware
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/middleware/

Comment: Perhaps it used to be the case, but Sentry's Django intergration does not currently receive user information by default. @Charanjit Singh's answer is correct.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned here: https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/python/guides/django/#configure

Set:

```
    # If you wish to associate users to errors (assuming you are using
    # django.contrib.auth) you may enable sending PII data.

    send_default_pii=True,
```

while configuring the sentry in Django.

**PII: Personal Identifiable Information**

P.S. Don't forget to include `django.contrib.auth` in your installed_apps.